# calling php function in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have one file json.js and one php function in php file .in json.js i want to check value returned by php function  if value returned by function is 0 jquery should perform :$(':input').prop('disabled', true); otherwise nothing –

```
function loadJson (table, id) {

    $.get("json-object.php", {'table': table, 'id':id}, function (data) {


        console.log(data);

        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            if ($('input[name="'+k+'"]').is('input[type="text"]')) {
                $('input[name="'+k+'"]').val(v);
            } 
            if($('select[name="'+k+'"]').val(v)){
                get_input_value(k,v);   

            } 


            if ($('input[name="'+k+'"]').is('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
                get_input_value(k,v);
            } 
         console.log(k+' ==> '+v);


        // Here I want to check condition of php function if value returned by fucntion is 0 it should perform :$(':input').prop('disabled', true); otherwise nothing //
        });
    }, 'json');
}
```

My php function:

```
function ronly($id) {

    //$id=$_POST['noces'];
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(noces) FROM alterdetail WHERE noces = '$id'";
    $sql.=';';
    //echo "QUERY <br/>";
    //echo $sql;
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

           if($row['COUNT(noces)'] > 0)
                { echo "you can not alter data";
                return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "   data new  ";
                return 1;
                }
   }
```

Comment: I want to check condition of php function if value returned by fucntion is 0 jquery should perform :$(':input').prop('disabled', true); otherwise nothing

Comment: Is the return value from PHP added in the AJAX response somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, as Javascript is client-side executed, and PHP is server-side executed ...

A "solution" would be to assign a Javascript variable into the PHP file that you'll read into the Javascript file, as variable are global.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery if possible.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.php', function() {
    alert('Function called');
});
```

Or try JQuery forms. Use a form to submit any data, and it'll give you the response as a text or JSon object.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit

Here is an example for you:

```
$('#anyForm').ajaxForm({
    url: "process.php?proc=7",
    dataType:  'html', 

    success: function(responseText) {
        if(responseText == "0") { 
            $(':input').prop('disabled', true); 
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: what is sellform here ? process.php is the file where i have my php function . data type should be html ok . in success can i use my condition in place of function ?

Comment: #sellForm is a <form>. You can do:

    if(responseText === 0) {
        $(':input').prop('disabled', true); 
    }

instead the alert. If that's what you want.